# Finding inverses to solve a system of congruences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

> Solve this system using the chinese remainder theorem. Find $x\in [-900,0]$.
>
> $x\equiv3\bmod{4}$
>
> $x\equiv7\bmod{9}$
>
> $x\equiv4\bmod{25}$

How do I go about this?

I've found $m=4*9*25=900$, and $M_1=225$ and $M_2=100$, $M_3=36$.

How do I find the inverses,$y_1,y_2,y_3$, so that $M_1y_1=1\mod4$ etc...?

Comment: There doesn’t exist an integer that is a multiple of 3 but with a remainder of 7 modulo 9. Perhaps there’s a mistake.

Comment: There was a mistake, edited now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Since $M_1=225\equiv 1\mod 4$, we get $y_1\equiv 1\mod 4$ for free. Similarly, $M_2=100\equiv 1\mod 9$ so $y_2\equiv 1\mod 9$. Finally, we have $M_3=36\equiv11\mod25$. This one is a little harder. We have $11\times 9=99\equiv -1\mod 25$, and thus $11\times(11\times 81)=(11\times9)^2\equiv1\mod 25$. Hence $$y_3\equiv 11\times 81\equiv 11\times 6=66\equiv 16\mod 25.$$

**Alternate Solution**

The first congruence says that $x=3+4n$ for some integer $a$. Substituting this into the second congruence, we have $$3 + 4a \equiv 7\mod 9\iff 4a \equiv 4\mod 9\iff a\equiv 1\mod 9.$$
Therefore $a=1+9b$ for some integer $b$, and thus $x= 3+4(1+9b)=7+36b$. Substituting this into the last congruence, we have 
$$7+11b\equiv 7+36b \equiv  4\mod 25\iff 11b\equiv-3\equiv22\mod 25\iff b\equiv 2\mod 25.$$
So $b=2+25c$ for some integer $c$, and thus $x=7+36(2+25c)=79+900c$. Taking $c=-1$ yields $x=-821$, which is in the required range.

**Comments**

Instead of finding the inverse of $11$ mod $25$, say, it was easier to simply use the properties of modular arithmetic until we were able to find $b$ by inspection.